# iOS - SWIFT - NMSSH Unable to get data from SFTS server into Data variable

Tags: ios, swift, nmssh

Using NMSSH and NMSFTP, I am able to connect to our company's remote SFTS server. I am also able to upload files to an "Incoming" folder in SFTS site. The issue is, when I try read a JSON file in the "Outgoing" folder using NMSFTP Contents(ofFile:), I keep getting NIL value. I am able to get the file name using contentsOfDirectory(atPath:). Any help is appreciated. The remote Windows 2019 server had read/write permissions for all folders I am dealing with

```
XCODE 12.0
iOS 14.0
```

Here is my code:

---

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { () in

        let empDownloadSession = NMSSHSession(host: "host_site:22",  andUsername: "user name")
        empDownloadSession.connect()
        if empDownloadSession.isConnected{
            print("Employee download session connected")
            empDownloadSession.authenticateBy(inMemoryPublicKey: nil, privateKey: self.privKey, andPassword: "password entered here")
            
            if empDownloadSession.isAuthorized == true {
                print("SFTP employee download session is authorized")
                let downloadSession = NMSFTP(session: empDownloadSession)
                downloadSession.connect()
                
                if downloadSession.isConnected {
                    print("Employee download session is connected")
                } else {
                    print("Error: employee download session not connected")
                    return
                }

                guard let employeeListContents = downloadSession.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: "/MailTracking/Test/Outgoing")
               else {
                    print("Unable to read contents of file in SSH site")
                    return
               }
                print("Printing Contents of file at path")
                print(employeeListContents)
                print("Employee data captured")
                
                guard let employeeList = downloadSession.contents(atPath:  "/MailTracking/Test/Outgoing/")
// this is where the issue is. I get nil value
               else {
                    print("Unable to read contents of file in SSH site")
                    return
               }
                print("Printing Contents of file at path")
                print(employeeList)
                do {
                    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: self.employeeList!, options: [])  as? [String : Any] {
                        
                        if let empList1 = json["employees"] as? [String] {
                        print("Employee Details ")
                        print(empList1)
                        }
                    }
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print("Unable to create json file from employeeList data")
                    print("Failed to load \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
                
            } else {
                print("empDownloadSession not authorized")
            }
        } else {
            print ("empDownloadSession is NOT connected")
        }
        empDownloadSession.disconnect()
    }
```

---

Log:

2020-11-09 10:00:21.150336-0500 My Application [23155:9533137] NMSSH: libssh2 (v1.8.0) initialized
2020-11-09 10:00:21.150739-0500 My Application[23155:9533137] NMSSH: Start our_company_sfts_site.com resolution
2020-11-09 10:00:31.164833-0500 My Application[23155:9533140] NMSSH: Socket connection to 149.32.227.28 on port 22 failed with reason -2, trying next address...
2020-11-09 10:00:31.397388-0500 My Application[23155:9533140] NMSSH: Socket connection to 149.32.195.28 on port 22 succesful
2020-11-09 10:00:32.226092-0500 My Application[23155:9533140] NMSSH: Remote host banner is SSH-2.0-9.99 sshlib
Employee download session connected
2020-11-09 10:00:32.226616-0500 My Application[23155:9533140] NMSSH: The host's fingerprint is XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:68:95:A4
2020-11-09 10:00:32.226952-0500 My Application[23155:9533140] NMSSH: SSH session started
2020-11-09 10:00:32.313983-0500 My Application[23155:9533140] NMSSH: User auth list: publickey,password
SFTP employee download session is authorized
2020-11-09 10:00:37.456136-0500 My Application[23155:9533140] NMSSH: Public key authentication succeeded.
Employee download session is connected
Printing Contents of file at path
[<NMSFTPFile: 0x28272c280> Filename: test.txt]
// Above file test.txt is last of several files I tried. All of them are.json files
Employee data captured
No Data file creation
2020-11-09 10:00:40.921732-0500 My Application [23155:9533140] NMSSH: Disconnected
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file My Application/SSHEmplyeeDownload.swift, line 97
2020-11-09 10:00:40.923135-0500 My Application[23155:9533139] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file My Application/SSHEmplyeeDownload.swift, line 97
(lldb)

Comment: Wondering if anyone had an approach or solution to above issue. We are still using a very convoluted workaround to address this situation